# How to get a data element within one's DIV

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the data value within an anchor element in a Div.

The code is as follows:-

```
<div id="value" class="wrapper-dropdown-5" tabindex="1">
    <img src="./images/content/value-menu-item-selected.png">
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="orange">
            <a href="#" data-jumpslide="2">
                  ...
```

I am trying to get the value of **data-jumpslide** within the **div id="value"**

Here is what I tried but clearly, it isn't working.

```
$("#value").data('jumpslide')
```

EDIT 2:

Tried this too.

```
$("#"+$(this).attr("id")+ " > a.data('jumpslide')").
```

Didn't work either :(
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jumpslide` is a property of a descendant of the div, not the div itself.  You need to select that descendant first, then you may retrieve the data.

```
$('ul.dropdown > li.orange > a', '#value').data('jumpslide')
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. What if I want to get the jumpslide based on the DIV. If I write $('div#value > ul.dropdown > li.orange > a', '#value').data('jumpslide') ... it returns undefined.

Comment: If you want to write it that way, you need to remove the `'#value'` second argument: `$('div#value > ul.dropdown > li.orange > a')...`. Either way should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use div with id defined as context why don't you use this?

```
$('#value li.orange a').data('jumpslide');
```

Returns:

```
2
```

Docs: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors

Answer (score 1):

```
//assuming that there is one element with data-jumpslide attribute inside #value
$('#value').find('[data-jumpslide]').data('jumpslide');
```